# Cefsharp with Winform: OnFocusedNodeChanged never called when the user changes the focus to another node

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

i'm trying to use OnFocusedNodeChanged to open the virtual keyboard when is needed with Cefsharp and Winform, but this method is never called. I'm using it wrong?

the code is:

```
class CMSRenderBrowser : IRenderProcessMessageHandler
{
    public void OnFocusedNodeChanged(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IDomNode node)
    {
        var message = node == null ? "lost focus" : node.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("OnFocusedNodeChanged() - " + message);
    }

    public void OnContextCreated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame)
    {
    }

    public void OnContextReleased(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame)
    {
    }


    public void OnUncaughtException(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, JavascriptException exception)
    {
    }
}
```

and this is the main form .cs:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com");
        browser.RenderProcessMessageHandler = new CMSRenderBrowser();

        this.Controls.Add(browser);
        
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to manually display a virtual keyboard? Are you having problems with the built in virtual keyboard handling?

Answer (score 0):

Because it involves sending messages from the render process to the browser process it's not enabled by default. You must enabled it by setting [CefSharpSettings.FocusedNodeChangedEnabled](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/84.4.x/html/P_CefSharp_CefSharpSettings_FocusedNodeChangedEnabled.htm) to true before you call `Cef.Initialize` (If you don't call `Cef.Initialize` yourself then before you create the first `ChromiumWebBrowser` instance).

```cs
//This must be set before Cef.Initialized is called
CefSharpSettings.FocusedNodeChangedEnabled = true;
```

The documentation should be updated to reflect this requirement (Feel free to submit a PR to https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp if you have time).

Comment: Oh thanks. on more last clarification: i'm wondering if this will slow down the user experience..

Comment: Unlikely, the number of messages sent will be a drop in the bucket compared to the number Chromium sends internally.